# Unique eigenvalue of maximal absolute value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $a_{ii}=0$ for all $i$, and $a_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i\neq j$, and $a_{ij}=0\leftrightarrow a_{ji}=1$ for all $i\neq j$. Is it necessary that $A$ as a unique, non-repeated eigenvalue of maximal absolute value?

I thought about applying the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices), but the matrix $A$ is not necessarily irreducible, and also the Perron–Frobenius theorem for irreducible matrices doesn't seem to say that the eigenvalue of maximal absolute value is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$, which has two zero eigenvalues;
or $\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}$, which is orthogonal, hence all eigenvalues have absolute value 1.